# Custom analystic platform?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to log search queries, the user's name, and datetime of the query to analyze at a further date such as view the amount of searches within a certain time frame, view a rank of top searches, a rank of users with the most searches, etc.

Does Google Analytics support this? If so, what should I look up to figure out how to get started? If not, are there other analytic platforms that would support this?

I'm having a difficult time finding the right terms to use to look this up. I'd prefer not to build an analytics platform from scratch if possible.

Comment: What kind of research do you mean? Do you have the user's name?

Comment: @MichelePisani Yes, I have the name, datetime, and query and would like to do things like view the amount of searches within a certain time frame, view a rank of top searches, a rank of users with the most searches, etc.

Comment: Do you mean internal search?

Comment: @MichelePisani I'm not sure what you mean by internal search, but what I'm doing is logging searches that people are making within my software.

Comment: I mean search inside your system, not search in google